Twolevel multgroup model in Mplus
I would like to use Mplus to run a two-level multigroup model with two groups (e.g. example 9.11 in the user guide).
My question: I have an independent variable X that varies in group A only between level 2 units, i.e. X is a between-only variable in group A.
Accordingly, I specify X as a "between=" variable. In group B, however, the same independent variable X varies both between and within groups. Is it possible to estimate such a model - and if so, how?

Mplus will not let you run this model. Anytime you try to run a type=twolevel multigroup model in which the grouping variable varies within clusters, it will give you an error. As noted by Linda Muthen, here, "The grouping variable should be a between-level variable. Using a within-level grouping variable violates the assumption that the groups contain independent observations."
It will not give you an error if instead you run the model as a multigroup model with the type=complex standard error correction. Of course, this will not be satisfactory if you have such things as random slopes in your model.  But if all you have are so-called fixed effect predictors, it is a potential workaround. Technically, it still violates the assumption noted above.
Otherwise, you would have to abandon the multigroup model and run the type=twolevel model with the grouping variable as a predictor at the %within% and %between% level. Note that to get something close to the parameter estimates you would get from a multigroup model, you would need to interact the grouping variables with all predictors as well as allow the residual variance to be predicted by the grouping variable. I wouldn't recommend doing this as that model is very likely overparameterized and likely to have significantly worse model fit than the model with the grouping variable simply as a predictor.
If you go this latter route, you will have to acknowledge in your writeup that the grouping variable does not vary within all clusters.
